# Authentication in OWASP ZAP 2.4.2 OSX

Tags: macos, owasp, zap

I've configured Authentication and Users as described in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cR4gw-cPZOA

However, it doesn't seem to actually use those credentials ( I see lots of posts to my authentication form with user "ZAP", and various other seemingly canned inputs, however) when I run Attack->Active Scan, and I cannot figure how to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

We've got more details in this FAQ: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth

Does that help?

Simon (ZAP project lead)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To add more information to my earlier question - if I set up ZAP as proxy, login to my web application via the browser that is using ZAP as proxy, and then right click a page I'm interested in (behind login) and add that to my Context, it will then be able to log in. However, is there a way to have it search for links it finds once logged in automatically and launch an attack against those (as long as they are wildcarded in my context) w/o manually adding all pages?

Comment: Yes, once you have set up authentication and user credentials you can Spider (and Active Scan for that matter) your app using any of the users whos details you've added. Look at the Spider dialog :)